# spark run ./bin/spark-submit --master local examples/src/main/python/sql/arrow.py

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

spark 2.3.1
python 2.7
java 1.8.0_144
When I run `./bin/spark-submit --master local examples/src/main/python/sql/arrow.py` ,report an error!
What should I do?

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using the ParNew young
>   collector with the Serial old collector is deprecated and will likely
>   be removed in a future release 20/06/15 17:34:52 WARN SparkConf: The
>   configuration key 'spark.scheduler.executorTaskBlacklistTime' has been
>   deprecated as of Spark 2.1.0 and may be removed in the future. Please
>   use the new blacklisting options, spark.blacklist.* 20/06/15 17:34:52
>   WARN SparkConf: The configuration key 'spark.akka.frameSize' has been
>   deprecated as of Spark 1.6 and may be removed in the future. Please
>   use the new key 'spark.rpc.message.maxSize' instead. 20/06/15 17:34:53
>   WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your
>   platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable Running Pandas
>   to/from conversion example Pandas DataFrame result statistics:
>                   0           1           2 count  100.000000  100.000000  100.000000 mean     0.484339    0.473602    0.528726 std      0.278308    0.299459    0.288117 min      0.013394    0.000500    0.006130 25%      0.254368    0.239107    0.295636 50%      0.474691    0.476180    0.531746 75%      0.688036    0.754475    0.778992 max      0.997862    0.994117    0.989650
>
> Running pandas_udf scalar example 0    1 1    4 2    9 dtype: int64
>   20/06/15 17:35:01 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0
>   (TID 1) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
>   java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageChannelReader.readNextMessage(MessageChannelReader.java:64)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageSerializer.deserializeSchema(MessageSerializer.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowStreamReader.readSchema(ArrowStreamReader.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.initialize(ArrowReader.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.ensureInitialized(ArrowReader.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.getVectorSchemaRoot(ArrowReader.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:114)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec$$anon$2.(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec.evaluate(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 20/06/15 17:35:01 ERROR
>   TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/data/home/work/clients/spark-2.3.1-SNAPSHOT-bin-2.7.2U12/examples/src/main/python/sql/arrow.py",
>   line 124, in 
>       scalar_pandas_udf_example(spark)   File "/data/home/work/clients/spark-2.3.1-SNAPSHOT-bin-2.7.2U12/examples/src/main/python/sql/arrow.py",
>   line 77, in scalar_pandas_udf_example
>       df.select(multiply(col("x"), col("x"))).show()   File "/usr/bin/hadoop/software/spark2.3/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py",
>   line 350, in show   File
>   "/usr/bin/hadoop/software/spark2.3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1160, in **call**   File
>   "/usr/bin/hadoop/software/spark2.3/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
>   line 63, in deco   File
>   "/usr/bin/hadoop/software/spark2.3/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
>   line 320, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling o134.showString. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0
>   in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver):
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
>   java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageChannelReader.readNextMessage(MessageChannelReader.java:64)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageSerializer.deserializeSchema(MessageSerializer.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowStreamReader.readSchema(ArrowStreamReader.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.initialize(ArrowReader.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.ensureInitialized(ArrowReader.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.getVectorSchemaRoot(ArrowReader.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:114)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec$$anon$2.(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec.evaluate(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2036)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2057)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2076)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:363)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3272)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3253)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3252)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2484)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2698)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
>   java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:334)     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageChannelReader.readNextMessage(MessageChannelReader.java:64)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.message.MessageSerializer.deserializeSchema(MessageSerializer.java:104)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowStreamReader.readSchema(ArrowStreamReader.java:128)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.initialize(ArrowReader.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.ensureInitialized(ArrowReader.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.arrow.vector.ipc.ArrowReader.getVectorSchemaRoot(ArrowReader.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:114)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:252)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec$$anon$2.(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowEvalPythonExec.evaluate(ArrowEvalPythonExec.scala:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:131)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     ... 1 more}

Comment: I can't define @pandas_udf("id long, v double", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP),will report error!But ,when I use spark3.0 it will work !

Comment: Please post your code as well

Comment: `from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType 

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 1.0), (1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (2, 5.0), (2, 10.0)],
    ("id", "v"))  
@pandas_udf("id long, v double", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)  
def normalize(pdf):
    v = pdf.v
    return pdf.assign(v=(v - v.mean()) / v.std())

    
df.groupby("id").apply(normalize).show()`

Comment: I resolve this quesion:pip install pyarrow==0.10.0